# How to add Element over fullscreen video on firefox

Tags: firefox, video, overlay, fullscreen

I need help about adding content over a Fullscreen video (embed in iframe) on Firefox ... I 'm able to do it in chrome without any issue ! but FF is not allowing me to ! 
I don't understand why and I'm looking for a solution now for days ! :(

If someone can help me, here is a jsfiddle example try to run it in firefox and you will see ... no way to get this work correctly everything is behind, z-index does not work on ff but it does on chrome.

remember it's only in fullscreen mode.

(I did not make the example working for chrome but it does not matter because i was able to do it just with playing with z-index property.)

This is the example:
    `Example`
https://jsfiddle.net/7ccf5pgw/4/

Thanks for  everything.

Cheers